# Change section numbering for appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, koma-script

For my appendix I'm trying to change 3 things to my section numbering:

1. Change to Alphabetical numbering
2. Subsections of the appendix are not supposed to appear in the table of contents
3. Numbering has to reset for my appendix, since I am using sections in my main part aswell

The result is supposed to look like this:

```
Appendix
A.1 Code 1
A.2 Code 2
```

For the table of contents its supposed to look like this:

```
5. Results ............. 50
Appendix ............... 51
```

I'm currently using the following code:

```
\documentclass[ DIV15,
liststotoc,
]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

{
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thesection\Alph{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\section*{Appendix}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\subsection{Code 1}
\subsection{Code 2}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\end{document}
```

TexStudio compiles with no errors, but the page numbering for my appendix is still numeric. How can I change the numbering to alphabetical?
I've tried \def instead of \renewcommand but it did not help.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Phyrii

Comment: Have you tried putting the `\appendix` command before the start of the appendix? If not then can you please expand your code snippets into a compliable [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In particular, it would help to know what document class you are using.

Comment: Okay the \appendix made a lot of my code obsolete. Doing everything of the above, it's not showing the page number in the table of contents, though. Any ideas? I also added my documentclass, sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

The line `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thesection\Alph{section}}` creates a recursion loop. I think that you probably want

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

Secondly, since you are suppressing the section number in your MWE by using `\section*`, and given what you actually say, I think that you probably want:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Of course, you may actually have real sections in your document, in which case you should use

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}]
```

You could also potentially use `\chapter` here and `\section` instead of `\subsection` (or you could ignore these comments:)?

Finally, I am not sure what the intention of the two `\addtocontents{toc}...` commands is. If you comment out these two lines then a small variation of your MWE produces what I think you want:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[ DIV15,
liststotoc,
]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\section*{Appendix}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\subsection{Code 1}
\subsection{Code 2}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that if you use \Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection} instead of A.\arabic{subsection}, this works even with multiple sections in the appendix.

Answer (score 0):

With a KOMA-Script class I would use:

```
\addsec{Appendix}%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=\parttocdepth}%
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  DIV=15,% <- syntax changed!
  listof=totoc,% <- syntax changed!
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
  \addsec{Appendix}%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=\parttocdepth}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument

\appendix
\subsection{Code 1}
\subsection{Code 2}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]